# Not Displaying Image From Controller

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I have a template selector on codeigniter which I use and I can switch between themes/templates.

I can not seem to get my image to display on the src to match the template that is selected when echoed from controller.

**config.php**

`$config['DIR_IMAGE'] = FCPATH . 'image/';`

**Controller**

```
if (empty($config_template)) {
$data['config_template'] = $this->configs->get('config_template');
}

$data['templates'] = array();

$directories = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/catalog/views/theme/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
$data['templates'][] = basename($directory);
}

// DIR_IMAGE is Defined AS FCPATH . 'image/';

// $this->configs->get('config_template') Autoloaded Lib Gets Current Name Of Theme Set On Database.

$data['templates_image'] =  config_item('DIR_IMAGE') . 'templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . 'png';
```

**On View**

`<img src="<?php echo $templates_image;?>" alt="" id="template" class="img-thumbnail" />`

Also Tried

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$data['templates_image'] = $this->load->image(config_item('DIR_IMAGE') . 'templates' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png');
```

No Luck

Comment: What is the output of <?php echo $templates_image;?>

Comment: Also are you passing $data to the view like this $this->load->view("view_file", $data);

Comment: Yes Loading view with $data The image should show a image of my theme in my image / template dir. all named correct.

Comment: Can you tell me the output of $templates_image. You can view source of your generated html.

Comment: check the folder image is present

Comment: On view if I do this `<img src="<?php echo base_url('image/templates/'. $templates_image . '.png');?>" alt="" id="template" class="img-thumbnail" />` works fine but would like to do it from controller. And added on controller this $data['templates_image'] = $this->configs->get('config_template');

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working now after trying something

Controller Added

`$data['image'] = base_url('image/templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png');`

View Added

`<img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="" id="template" class="img-thumbnail" />`